# Solve this equation: $(x+2)(\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1})+\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Solve this equation: $(x+2)(\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1})+\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}=1$

---

This is my try

> Let $t=\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1}$ or $t^2=6x+7-4\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}=1$
>
> The equation is equivalent to: $t^2-4(x+2)t-6x-3=0\qquad(*)$

I have no idea how to solve the equation $(*)$. Who can help me?

Comment: $-1$ seems to work...

Comment: Yeap, $\dfrac{-1}{2}$ and $3$ also seem to work

Comment: Do you need details on how to find the solution, or just that $-1$, $-1/2$, and $3$ are the only solutions?

Comment: I need details on how to find the solution, please!

Comment: @bburGsamohT I hope, simplier/more elegant, than mine :)

Comment: All solutions are $x=\left(-1,\frac{-1}{2},3,-2\right)$. Note that $x=-2$  is valid if the function can be Complex Valued.

Answer (score 2):

$$
(x+2)(\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1})+\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}=1
$$
Let $t=x+1$,
$$2x+3=2t+1$$
$$(t+1)(\sqrt{2t+1}-2\sqrt{t})+\sqrt{2t^2+t}=1$$
$$(t+1)(\sqrt{2t+1}-2\sqrt{t})=1-\sqrt{2t^2+t}$$
Squaring both sides,
$$(t^2+2t+1)(2t+1+4t-4\sqrt{2t^2+t})=1+2t^2+t-2\sqrt{2t^2+t}$$
$$6t^3+12t^2+6t+t^2+2t+1-\sqrt{2t^2+t}(-4t^2-8t-2)=1+2t^2+t$$
$$t(6t^2+11t+7)=\sqrt{t}\sqrt{2t+1}(-4t^2-8t-2)$$
Again Squaring both sides,
$$
4t^6-12t^5-19t^4+10t^3+9t^2-4t=0
$$
Therefore , $t=-1,0,\frac{1}{2},4$
$$
x=-2,-1,-\frac{1}{2},3
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+2)(\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1})+\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}=1$$
$$(x+2)(\sqrt{2x+3}-2\sqrt{x+1})=1-\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}$$
$$(x+2)^2(6x+7-4\sqrt{(2x+3)(x+1)})=2x^2+5x+4-2\sqrt{2x^2+5x+3}$$
$$(x+2)^2(6x+7)-(2x^2+5x+4)=2(2(x+2)^2-1)\sqrt{(2x+3)(x+1)})$$
$$(6 x^3+29 x^2+47 x+24)^2=4(2x^2+8x+7)^2(2x+3)(x+1)$$
Latter can be factored as roots $-1,\,-\frac{1}{2},3$ are known.

[$\frac{4 x^6+12 x^5-19 x^4-106 x^3-135 x^2-68 x-12 }{(x+\frac{1}{2})(x+1)(x-3)}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284+x%5E6%2B12+x%5E5-19+x%5E4-106+x%5E3-135+x%5E2-68+x-12+%29%2F%28%28x%2B1%2F2%29*%28x%2B1%29*%28x-3%29%29)$=2 (2 x+1) (x+2)^2$